# How to pass data from a view to a controller - yii

Tags: php, templates, yii

I've created a form using the standard yii crud system that holds all of the "paylists" on a certain account. Within each of the paylists there are certain recipients. (i.e. john might be in the paylist for "workers in march", while suzy would be in the pay list "workers in may"). I am trying to create a button in _view.php that allows me to redirect to the recipient page *and* passes in the information of which list he choice (Which I call list_id).

I've been trying to do this all within the view with a link. This is in _view.php

```
<?php 
$list_id = $data->id;
echo CHtml::link('Manage',array('recipient/index', 'list_id'=>$list_id)); 
?>
```

But, in my controller I am unable to call $list_id. Should I be doing this in a different way? Should  I be trying to pass data from my view to my controller at all?

**___________________** *EDIT*

The controller looks like this after the edits suggested

```
public function actionIndex($list_id)
    {
        // echo $_GET["id"];
        $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Recipient', array('criteria'=>array(
                                                'condition'=>'list_id = '.$list_id)));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: that should work, how are you fetching list_id parameter in your index action..? can you share your controller code as well..

Comment: define "list_id" parameter for index action, e.g. actionIndex($list_id = null)

Comment: In general you should not pass a large amount of data via url parameter. However this seems to be only an ID. Please show us your controller.

Comment: What does adding $list_id = null do? How is this different form simply having actionIndex($list_id) ?

Comment: The controller looks like this 

public function actionIndex($id)
 {
  // echo $_GET["id"];
  $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Recipient', array('criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'list_id = '.$id)));
  $this->render('index',array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  ));
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii has added support for automatic action parameter binding. a controller action method can define named parameters whose value will be automatically populated from $_GET by Yii.

for example :

```
public function actionIndex($list_id)
```

You can use the example above or simply call by using $_GET['list_id']

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Pass value like this in the view file

```
echo CHtml::link('Manage',array("recipient/index/list_id/$list_id"));
```

and your index function in controller should be like this:-

```
public function actionindex($list_id = null)
{
   echo $list_id;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me I used 
echo CHtml::link('Manage',array('recipient/index/id/$list_id')) and in my controller  I have the function actionIndex take in $id